# Calculating the acquisition time of a sample and hold circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, adc

I've learning about analog to digital converters. I came to read about the acquisition time of sample and hold circuit. But it confuses me. Can anyone help me to learn how to calculate the acquisition time of a sample and hold circuit ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAYjJO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say we have a 8 bit SAR,
Resistor value = R;
Capacitor value = C;

How do we calculate the acquisition time ?

(Do not bother about the Op-Amp)

Comment: You need to calculate how long it takes C1 to charge up (to within your required accuracy of the final value) through R1.

Comment: You need to know the accuracy you require, to answer the question properly. But for a crude answer, 10*RC will be better than 0.1% error.

Comment: @BrianDrummond There was a term saying that "error introduced by this process should be less than the equivalent of half of 1 LSB"
Can you explain it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst-case distance from the final solution in terms of voltage on C1 is (from the step response of an RC-filter):

$$
V(t)=V_{max}\exp(-t/(R_1C_1))
$$

Where \$V_{max}\$ is the maximum input swing (change per sample). 
Now you might want to settle a bit more than LSB. In terms of a relative deviation of (an arbitrary) 1/4th of LSB you can write:

$$
 LSB/4 = \exp(-t/(R_1C_1)) \\
 \log(LSB/4) = -t/(R_1C_1) \\
 t = - (R_1C_1)\log(LSB/4) 
$$

Since you have 8 bits, LSB relative to 1 is \$2^{-8}\$. Then the above formula yields about 0.301 ms.